# How to collect logs from android application ported to BB10

Tags: android, blackberry-10, android-logcat

I'm trying to collect application logs from customers BB10 device using aLogCat from BB10 BlackBerry World. On my device I menage to see all the application logs with no problem, but customer claims that that he can't see any logs using the same aLogCat.
Can't find any permission options that can be responsible.

What might be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Same problem on my side, blank log on BlackBerry Q10, OS 10.2.1.2102...